# time between dates matlab (etime)

Tags: matlab, datetime, time

I'm trying to get the time elapsed (in seconds) between 2 measurements, I have the dates and times for each one.
I tried to use etime but I get this error over and over:

"Index exceeds matrix dimensions.

Error in etime (line 40)
t = 86400*(datenummx(t1(:,1:3)) - datenummx(t0(:,1:3))) + ..."

First I was using the dates like datetime data, but I read that input arguments of etime had to be datevectors, so I convert the data to datevec but I keep getting this error.

My code:

```
time_v = datevec(FH);
for i = 1:length(ind_med);
    dateAVGI = date(ind_med(i));
    dateAVG  = [dateAVG;dateAVGI];
    timeAVGI = etime(time_v(ind_fin(i)),time_v(ind_med(i)));
    timeAVG  = [timeAVGI;timeAVG];
end
```

ind_med and ind_fin are column vectors containing the index of the data in which I want to get the time.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I solve it, i forgot to put the columns in the index.

```
etime(time_v(ind_fin(i),:),time_v(ind_med(i)),:)
```